# Using a map for tuple in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have an RDD in format `[(("doc1", ("ab","bc","cd",...)),("doc2", ("de","ab","ab",...)))...]`

Can we map this to an RDD of format `[((ab, (doc1, doc2,...)),(bc, (doc1, doc2,...))]`

Comment: `flatMap` to flatten the original rdd and then `groupByKey` to re-aggregate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if your list contains a single tuple or multiple tuples by looking at the code you provided.
Assuming you have an `rdd` of `tuples`, you can apply

1. `flatMap` to *flatten* the second element of the original `tuple`, then apply
2. `reduceByKey` to aggregate the result into `tuples` of `(key, list)`, then apply
3. `map` to convert the inner `lists` back to `tuples`

```py
rdd = (sc.parallelize([("doc1", ("ab","bc","cd")), ("doc2", ("de","ab","ab"))])
       .flatMap(lambda x: [(i, [x[0]]) for i in x[1]])
       .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
       .map(lambda x: (x[0], tuple(x[1]))))
print(rdd.collect())
```

```
[('cd', ('doc1',)), ('bc', ('doc1',)), ('ab', ('doc1', 'doc2', 'doc2')), ('de', ('doc2',))]
```